# How do I provide help for my .NET application?

Tags: .net

I'd like to write and distribute a help system with my application, that allows people to search for keywords, look at tables of contents, etc.
I also want the same help available offline and online.
What utility should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of commercial tools available.

If you want a free one you could get HTML help Workshop from Microsoft [(This has all info about that)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms670169(VS.85).aspx). [On this page there is even more info including a list to other tools](http://www.mshelpwiki.com/wiki/tiki-index.php?page=HTMLHelp).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Adobe RoboHelp](http://www.adobe.com/products/robohelp/)

Comment: I personally wouldn't be willing to spend $999 on something like that, but maybe that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [Help & Manual](http://www.helpandmanual.com/) for years - and love it.